# Javascript Filter Refactor

Tags: javascript, filter

I am filtering an array of objects using a function that looks like this

```
 var val = 'some text value'  

 this.someList = this.someList.filter(containsQuery);

        function containsQuery(listItem) {

        return   listItem.Key_One.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1 ||
                 listItem.Key_Two.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1 ||
                 listItem.Key_Three.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1
        }
```

My question is what is a better way of filtering on each of the list item key values without having to write a new line for each one? i.e so I can avoid going

```
listItem.Key_Four.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1
listItem.Key_Five.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1
```

etc..

Any advice would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use get keys of the object with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and iterate with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
function containsQuery(listItem) {
    return Object.keys(listItem).some(function (k) {
        return listItem[k].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, array containing all the keys and loop them?

Like

```
var keys = ['key_one', 'key_two', 'key_three', 'key_four'];
for (i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
if (listItem[keys[i]].toLowerCase().indexOf(val) > -1) return true;
}
return false;
```

Ah damn, same idea as above, just took too long writing :D